# Custom UIView as navigationItem title

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, xib, uinavigationitem

I want to create simple custom view and use it for navigationItem.titleView. My custom view is very simple, has only image view and label: [image]-[label]. I have xib file where I have defined all constraints (both subviews has constraint to superview - I want to height and width of subviews determine height and width of entire custom view). The problem is that when I instantiate view from xib like this:

```
class func titleViewWithTitle(title: String, icon: UIImage?) -> TitleView {
        let titleView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TitleView", owner: self, options: nil).first as TitleView       
        titleView.title.text = title
        titleView.icon.image = icon
        titleView.layoutSubviews()
        return titleView
    }
```

the size of this view is not determined by it's children. It has the size that was manually set in Interface Builder. What can I do to force the view to dynamically calculate size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom view, override the layoutSubviews method and add this:

```
CGSize targetSize = [self     systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
```

Create a CGRectFrame from this and set this frame as a new frame for self (which is the custom view).

This will basically find the smallest possible frame that still encompasses its content in a way that all content is shown.

Note: All subviews of this custom view must have autolayout compression resistance set properly. I.e. they must resist shrinking.

Comment: I have idea: i can implement `sizeToFits(size:CGSize)` and inside that method return the result of method `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize`. I have tried this but the view was wider that when I manully modify it's frame. Do you know what can be a problem?

Comment: I wrote the name of method wrong, sorry. The proper name is `sizeThatFits(size: CGSize)`. Description from apple doc : Asks the view to calculate and return the size that best fits the specified size. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/

Comment: hi i have problem with  size of this my  title inside ox XIB file out of frame & go to back button :(